# is it possible to display the latest commit when i use "git branch"?

Tags: git, commit

So, on each branch if I do "git log" or "git lg", it will show a list of commits done.

Now, is there a way to display the latest commit on each branch when I enter "git branch -arg"? I find it a bit annoying/tedious to have to checkout each branch then check the commits using "git log".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`git branch -v` lists branch names and the SHA and commit message of the latest commit on each branch.

See the [git branch manual page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can add a post-checkout hook ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504724/a-git-hook-for-whenever-i-change-branches)).

Basically, create the `.git/hooks/post-checkout` file and put whatever git command you want to run in it, and finally make sure to make that file executable (`chmod +x .git/hooks/post-checkout` on unix-like systems, such as Mac OS, GNU/Linux, etc).

For example, if you put `git show` in that file, it will automatically show you the last commit and what changes were made whenever you switch branch.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple `git log` parameters to control its output:

Like `--branches`, `--glob`, `--tag`, `--remotes` to select which commits to show, `--no-walk` to avoid showing all their history (just their tips as you want), `--oneline` shows only the first line of commit logs, `--decorate` and `--color=always` add more eye candy :D

Try these commands:

```
$ # show the first line of the commit message of all local branches
$ git log --oneline --decorate --color=always --branches --no-walk

$ # show the whole commit message of all the branches that start with "feature-"
$ git log --decorate --color=always --branches='feature-*' --no-walk

$ # show the last commit of all remote and local branches 
$ git log --decorate --color=always --branches --remotes --no-walk

$ # show the last commit of each remote branch
$ git fetch
$ git log --decorate --color=always --remotes --no-walk
```

BTW, there's no need to switch branches to see other branch's commits:

```
$ # show the 'otherbranch' last commit message
$ git log --decorate --color=always -n 1 otherbranch

$ # show a cool graph of the 'otherbranch' history
$ git log --oneline --decorate --color=always --graph otherbranch
```

Comment: ok, i found the correct switch to avoid traversing the branch history, use `--no-walk` with `--branches`

Answer (score 0):

If not explicitly requested, `git branch ...` will only show *local* branches.

The `-a` option will show local as well as *remote-tracking* branches.

Also useful: when using the *double-verbose* `-vv` option, the output will additionally show for each local branch the relationship to its remote target branch, if such relationship exists:

```
git branch -avv
```

([official *git-branch* documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))